# Trying to check if a word string is in a text file and I encountered StopIteration Error. I'm not sure why (closed)

Tags: python, function, file-handling

Here is the function I'm trying to run:

```
def parsefile(file_name,d_name):
    with open(file_name) as fn:
        if "Station" in fn.read():
            next(fn)
            for line in fn:
                (stat,north,east) = line.split()
                d_name[stat] = (north,east)
        else:
            print("Please input correct file with header: Stations, Northings, Eastings")

    
    return d_name
```

Here is a snippet of my text file:

```
Station Northings   Eastings
1   10001.00    10001.00
2   10070.09    10004.57
3   10105.80    10001.70
```

Comment: What do you expect `next` after `read`ing *everything*?

Answer (score 1):

The result of `open` (i.e. `fn`) is an iterator. An iterator gives values with `next()`, which raises `StopIteration` when the iterator is exhausted. `for .. in ...` construct (and many functions that handle iterators) will handle this exception for you.

`fn.read()` reads the whole file, after which there is nothing more to read, effectively exhausting the iterator; requesting the next value from `fn` raises `StopIteration`. If you want to go back to being able to read the file from start, you can use the `fn.seek(0)` to rewind the file pointer; however, note that some file handles cannot be rewound (notably, standard input).

Comment: Thank you! I see why I should not have used simply just `fn.read()`.